# Lightdm Won't Start in Test Mode With OpenRC

Tags: display-manager, lightdm, funtoo, logind, openrc

I have a funtoo installation and I recently did `sudo emerge x11-misc/lightdm` which appeared to work fine, but attempting to start lightdm in test mode with `sudo lightdm --test-mode` gives this:

```
** (lightdm:12656): WARNING **: Failed to get list of logind seats: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.login1 was not provided by any .service files
```

This is strange because I (think) am using openrc, not systemd (which I believe provides logind).

I don't think systemd is installed because `equery f systemd` says `No installed packaged matching systems` and I wish to keep it this way. Is it possible to configure LightDM to *not* use systemd?

Comment: I think am having the same problem as you. On my system, lightdm installs fine but `sudo lightdm --test-mode` gives me the same warning as you got. But beware: it really is a warning, not an error. So it is possible you can find more clues in `/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log`. Could you edit your post to include the contents of this file? Also, can you tell us which of these USE flags you have enabled `systemd` `introspection` `gnome`? And which profile do you have enabled?

Comment: `Is it possible to configure LightDM to not use systemd?`
Unlike a certain other DM, LightDM does not need systemd to function.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, because I did not have `pantheon` installed, the problem with lightdm not starting up was to remove the `enlightenment` overlay and then to install the ebuild supplied by Gentoo themselves.